# Using a variable value as angular tag attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am working with Angular 8 , I have come up with a scenario where based on data from json , I would like to render the icon accordingly . I want the name attribute of the tag to be dynamic .

```
<tr *ngFor="let something of somethings"
    (click)="open = !open; $event.stopPropagation()">
  <td>{{ something.name }}</td>
  <td>
    <ux-icon name="social-twitter"> // This attribute name value needs to come from json . i.e social-twitter
    </ux-icon>
```

Comment: Store it in a variable and then access it on the template.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your variable in square braces if you want to use a variable in template.
Without square braces it will consider it as a string

```
<tr *ngFor="let something of somethings" (click)="open = !open; $event.stopPropagation()">

        <td >{{ something.name }}</td>

        <td >

          <ux-icon [name]="social_twitter"> // This attribute name value needs to come from json . i.e social-twitter
         </ux-icon>  </td></tr>
```

where `social_twitter` is a variable in typescript.